# Best way to figure out which dev entry a drive maps to?

Tags: linux, hardware, storage, hard-drive

Have multiple drives on the server. I'm booting up to rescue mode and seems like the `/dev/sd*` do not map in the same sequence as normal.

What is the best way to figure out which drive is which? Perhaps just giving me the manufacture information or by connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different approaches.  First you can try mounting the various /dev/sd* devices and looking at their contents.

If you're using LVM, the volumes should appear in /dev/vgname/lvname no matter what /dev/sd* devices they come up as.  Same for software raid devices (MD).

If your disks have labels, there is probably a map in /dev/disk/by-label.

If you keep your fstab by UUID (not a bad idea), there's a map in /dev/disk/by-uuid/.

Comment: Hm, I don't seem to have by-label on my box (Fedora 13).

Comment: I just found `parted -l` and like that option better but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-id`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the command:  df -a

It shows the name of each device /dev/sd* and where its mounted, it also gives some filesystem usage statistics.

Also you could look at the contents of /etc/fstab but if your devices aren't mapping as usual, then maybe this file won't be correct.